# Integrating 2 search methods and aggregate results

Tags: sql, database, mongodb, rest, search

### Background

My search engine displays results from querying a remote API (not owned by me)
As well as by looking within a local database.

- Some documents appear only in the API response.
- Some documents appear only in my local DB
- Some documents appear in both the API response and my local DB

### Here's how:

Currently, whenever the API is queried, the results of the query are autosaved to my local DB, thus every document retrieved in the API query once will be available locally for future searches.

However, users can add documents to my local DB directly which mean they only appear in the local DB but not in the remote API.

### What I'm trying to figure out

I would like to display the most relevant search results to the users.

But:

- if I query only the local DB, relevant results that have not been scraped from the remote API will be missing.
- If I query only the remote API, locally uploaded documents will be missing.
- If I query both, I will potentially have duplicate documents retrieved once from the API and once locally.

Of course, I can cross-compare each document to see if its the same to avoid displaying duplicates but that sounds like an unreasonably expansive process.

### Data structure:

a document retrieved from the server will have a unique identifier (DOI) created remotely.
This DOI will be copied to the local DB. So DB docs that originated from the API have this DOI.

Documents that were originally created locally will NOT have a DOI.

Regardless, every document in the local DB has a local unique ID.

a document may have a:

- title
- date_created (if created locally)
- date_retrieved (if scraped from the API)
- DOI (if scraped from the API)
- authors: [array of names]
- publisher
- ... other meta data

### How would you approach this problem?

Comment: what would qualify a document/result to be considered a duplicate? title/url/etc? or do they all use the same ID field? add a few duplicate samples to your question if you can.

Comment: I added a "data structure" description to the question. Let me know if this is helpful. In short: a duplicate will have the same DOI value.